# Listar em HTML table separado por categoria

Tags: python, html5, django, front-end, pycharm

Estou em um desenvolvimento utilizando Python e Django e como IDE o pycharm.

Tenho uma lista vindo via Rest por mobile, com o nome de 'Atletas', e vem com as colunas "nome", "categoria", "tempo".

Gostaria de listar esses atletas em um HTML TABLE, porem separado por categoria e de ordem decrescente por TEMPO. (Cada categoria separado por um HTML TABLE)

Como fazer?

Comment: O que seria "separado por um html table"? Cada categoria em uma tabela?

Comment: Voxê precisa por um pouco do código e o ofmato dos dados que tem em mãos - não dá pra responder a pergunta assim. Ponha o código da view que você tem, e um exemplo com algumas linhas dos dados que você tem para exibir.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você trás os dados do banco você deve setar como order_by desc. Ex:

```
Atletas.objects.filter(categorias='spfc').order_by('-tempo')
```

Trás todos os jogadores que está no time do spfc com o tempo decrescente

Answer (score 0):

Você quer um output assim?

```
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0lax">nome</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">categoria</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">tempo</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">João</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">futebol</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Maria</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">basquete</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">José</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">volei</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">30</td>
  </tr>
</table>


| nome  | categoria | tempo |
|-------|-----------|-------|
| João  | futebol   | 20    |
| Maria | basquete  | 40    |
| José  | volei     | 30    |
```

Mas precisamos de mais informações. Naõ dá pra responder sem tem um exemplo melhor do seu input e uma explicação do que você quer. Mas principalmente, temos que saber o que você já está fazendo, quais o erros encontrados, etc?